# Android load full image with recyclerview, cardview and volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

The following is my recyclerview using php mysql and volley library in the attached image. As of now when one clicks the displayed image a toast of the image name appears as seen. Is it possible to load the full image using volley on click instead of the toast message?. Thank you in advance

[image]

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick = new ArrayList<>();

        ListOfdataAdapter = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManagerOfrecyclerView = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerOfrecyclerView);

        JSON_HTTP_CALL();

        // Implementing Click Listener on RecyclerView.
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

            GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                    return true;
                }

            });
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                view = Recyclerview.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

                if(view != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {

                    //Getting RecyclerView Clicked Item value.
                    RecyclerViewItemPosition = Recyclerview.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

                    // Showing RecyclerView Clicked Item value using Toast.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.get(RecyclerViewItemPosition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });


    }

    public void JSON_HTTP_CALL(){

        RequestOfJSonArray = new JsonArrayRequest(HTTP_JSON_URL,

                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        ParseJSonResponse(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        requestQueue.add(RequestOfJSonArray);
    }

    public void ParseJSonResponse(JSONArray array){

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

            DataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new DataAdapter();

            JSONObject json = null;
            try {

                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitle(json.getString(Image_Name_JSON));

                // Adding image title name in array to display on RecyclerView click event.
                ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.add(json.getString(Image_Name_JSON));

                GetDataAdapter2.setImageUrl(json.getString(Image_URL_JSON));

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ListOfdataAdapter.add(GetDataAdapter2);
        }

        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(ListOfdataAdapter, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a new activity including a viewimage . And add your image to viewimage

Comment: How do i do that Sir?. I have the intend but image is not coming

Comment: In your desired location you must call camera intent(for example) or a prepared image picker (or using of file and folder picker libs) after getting of your image(from camera or from your phone location) in onActivityResult get it. And then call new activity with path of your image.Also if you want , you could insert viewpager in your main activity(the activity that has onActivityResult method )and directly use  returning "data" Extra and add to viewpager(of course "data"  is suitable for icon usage). I correct my previous comment : **ViewPager**